# error when compiling my solidity file with python

Tags: solidity, python, py-solc-x

**Here is my deploy.py code**

[image]

The error message I got
[image: Error message]

I added all solcx python packages.

Comment: Please, provide source code as text, that way it is easier to test and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with solcx

so to sort this out I used

> pip install py-solc-x==0.5.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the key `Outputselection` is incorrectly capitalized. It should be `outputSelection`.